# Vacation Calculation based on Anniversary Date

Tags: function, ms-access, if-statement, calculated-field

The rule is after you first year of employment, based on your anniversary date, you get 40 hours. (ex. I was hired on 05/12/2011, I get 40 hours vacation on 05/12/2012.)

Then each subsequent year it rolls to calendar year. So using my above example I need to use my 40 hours between 05/12/2012 and 12/31/2012, because on 01/01/2013 my forty starts over.

At three years (01/01/2014), calendar date, I would get 80 hrs.

At 10 years, calendar date, it goes to 120. The code I am using is below but it doesn't come out right...

```
Function calcVacEarned(asOfDate As Date, HireDate As Date)
    Dim anniversary As Boolean
    Dim yos As Integer
    anniversary = False
    yos = Year(asOfDate) - Year(HireDate)

    If Month(HireDate) = Month(asOfDate) And (yos = 1) Then
      If Day(HireDate) <= Day(asOfDate) Then
        anniversary = True
    End If
    ElseIf Month(HireDate) < Month(asOfDate) And (yos = 1) Then
        anniversary = True
    End If

    If anniversary Then
        calcVacEarned = 40
    Else
        Select Case yos
          Case Is > 10
            calcVacEarned = 120
          Case Is > 3
            calcVacEarned = 80
          Case Is > 1
            calcVacEarned = 40
          Case Else
            calcVacEarned = 0
        End Select
    End If

End Function
```

My company uses this on a daily basis to calculate hours across the board, could use some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `calcVacEarned` will never change if `yos` anything other than 1, because `anniversary` will always be true if it hits that code block.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're returning the correct integer for `yos` :

```
If anniversary Then
    Select Case yos
    Case 1
        MsgBox "You actually get vacation"
    Case 2
        MsgBox "OP said nothing regarding 2 years!"
    Case 3
        MsgBox "You get 80 hours!"
    Case 10
        MsgBox "You get 120 hours!"
    End Select
End If
```